# Create godoc URL with different link text

Tags: go, godoc

According to the ["Godoc: documenting Go code"](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) blog post:

> URLs will be converted to HTML links; no special markup is necessary.

However, is there a way to create an HTML link with different link text than the URL?

Answer (score 4):

Go 1.19 introduced a format for specifying the link text.  The link text is written inline between square brackets: `[Link Text]`.  The link target is specified on a separate line like this:

```
[Link Text]: https://example.com/link/target
```

See the [Go Doc Comment documentation](https://tip.golang.org/doc/comment#links) for the complete details.

---

Answer for Go 1.18 and earlier:

Godoc.org linkifies text like "RFC 1234" to the online RFC [(example here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket)).

With that exception, the godoc tool and godoc.org do not provide a way to use text different from the URL.